# rmse value meaning

Tags: rms

```
rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_val,y_pre))
print('Val RMSE: %.3f' % rmse)
```

> Val RMSE: 1.825

I got this value for RMSE value but not sure what this number means

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It means that on average your prediction is at a distance of 1.825 away from the true value. As for saying if this is good or bad, it depends on the scale of your data. If your target outputs are all within 0-5 then on average you are almost 35% away from where you should be. If you scale is much larger than this can be quite good. A good way to know is see how this RMSE progressed throughtout training